# Why does the concept of a unitary matrix seem so similar to that of an invertible matrix?

Tags: quantum-gate

I understand that the intuition behind a unitary operator is that it preserves the length of the vector it acts upon. Also $U^\dagger U = I$. Doesn't that just mean that $U$ is just an invertible operator which preserves distance? And that $U^\dagger$ is the inverse?

**If not**, where am I making my mistake in reasoning? How should I rewire my thinking to avoid this flawed paradigm?

**If so**, does that then mean that all distance preserving and invertible operators are also normal operators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the definitions of a unitary $-$ a (bounded) linear surjective map that preserves distances (the inner product). From this it can be deduced that $U$ is invertible and $U^{-1} = U^\dagger$.

Also, it's enough to require the preservation of the lengths of all vectors (instead of all inner products) due to [Polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity)

Unitaries are normal because $U^\dagger U =  U U^\dagger$, clearly.

Comment: Nice getting the requirement of surjectivity - people often miss that. But doesn't boundedness follow automatically from the norm-preserving property? Is that why you put "(bounded)" in parentheses?